# RDWeb problems on Windows 10 (patch 1803) - Windows in background

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

We're a software developer currently oferring a Cloud version of our software, hosted in a remote virtual machine. Our customers access this virtual machine via RDWeb, seeing (and working with) only the program.

Since the mentioned update (1083), our customers' computers running on Windows 10 are reporting a problem in which whenever they open a new windows in our software, that window is automatically moved to the background, behind other windows they may have opened in our software. That causes them to believe the program has crashed, and is seriously interfering with their line of work. The only common ground we've been able to find is the operating system (Windows 10) and that they had recently installed an update (specifically, the 1083 patch).

Has anyone had similar issues? If so, how have you managed to solve them?

Thanks in advance for your help and your patience

Jaime Peña

Kherian Soft, S.L.

Comment: Can you please clarify what versions of Windows 10 are on both the client and the server? It is not clear if 1803 is the version on the client or only the server or both.

Comment: Also, this probably belongs to superuser.com since it is not a programming question.

Comment: FYI, got some info, this is a known issue that will be fixed ASAP in a future KB.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll make sure to use superuser.com next time.

Comment: Although off-topic for this site. There is a temporary patch available here: https://www.gotomyerp.com/blog/windows-10-update-to-build-1803/ It basically replaces two remote desktop files with a previous version. I tried it and it works for me.